# How may possible distinct pass words

Tags: probability

Making password based on three conditions
1. Choosing 3  letters without replacement (only capital letters) 
2. Choosing 2 digits with replacement
3. The first one should be one of choosen letters

My answer is 
26*25*24*10*10*(4P2)*(4C2)

But I am not sure if it is right. 
Please help me out.

Comment: Choosing $3$ letters without replacement gives $26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24$ possibilities. Choosing $2$ digits with replacement gives $10 \cdot 10$ possibilities. I don't understand the third condition - you mean the first character of the password has to be a letter not a number?

Comment: Yes you are right. And rest of four characters are shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  There are different approaches, but I would just pick each character and keep track of the restrictions as we go.  You have $26$ choices for the first character, because it has to be a letter.  How many choices for the second character?  Now split between whether that is a letter or number.  Keep going and you will be done.  For longer passwords it would be useful to combine the choices where you have three characters, two letters and one digit, regardless of whether you have LLD or LDL, but here is isn't so important.